# ionic 2 stripe payment issue

Tags: angularjs, ionic3, stripe-payments

i am developing `Hybrid` app using `ionic-3`. i want to make payment with stripe. i am getting token-id from card detail but i don't know how to make charges after getting token-id in angular 2. I did:

```
npm install stripe
```

and I got the stripe module into node_modules folder. This is my payment function for get token-id now i want to make charges.

```
   pay() {
    this.stripe.setPublishableKey('pk_test...');
    this.stripe.createCardToken(this.cardinfo).then((token) => {
    console.log("token.id")
    })
    .catch(error => 
    console.log(error)
  );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create charges server-side with your Secret Key, so you'll need to post the Token ID to a server-side endpoint that can do that for you: https://stripe.com/docs/charges

Edit: also, you can't use the Stripe Node library client side; it doesn't have those functions in it.  You need Elements for that part: https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js

Comment: yes, i tried that but i got an error in 'var stripe = require("stripe")("sk_test_BQokikJOvBiI2HlWgH4olfQ2");' require error. i have also install 'npm install stripe' but still getting error.

Comment: Cannot find name 'require'.

Comment: Are you doing the `require("stripe")` server side, in Node?  If not, then it's not going to work.  The `stripe` NPM module is not meant for client-side use at all - you need to use Elements/Stripe.js for that.